# WMI, Getting the W3WP IIS process requests per second

Tags: c#, iis, wmi, w3wp

I'm trying to monitor my IIS server and one of the thing i want to monitor is the web requests per second of the W3WP default process of the IIS.

I've already tried it in C# code with PerformanceCounter class and it was very slow procedure and performance.
I've found that the WMI queries are useful and highly performed, but I couldn't find any WMI class suitable for my needs. I've found that there is a 'Win32_perfFormattedData_W3SVC_WebService' class but all of the result's values were null or zero.

Is there something I've missed, or there is a different class of WMI queries I can use in order to get the requests per second?

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with the class named `Win32_PerfFormattedData_W3SVCW3WPCounterProvider_W3SVCW3WP`.

You can see the values via Powershell like this: `Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_W3SVCW3WPCounterProvider_W3SVCW3WP | Format-List -Property Name, RequestsPerSec`